# Getting firebird to work under OSX with Delphi Firemonkey app

Tags: macos, delphi, firebird, firemonkey

Does anyone know of a guide to getting Firebird working under OSX for Delphi apps?

I am using the InterBase Express components but when I start my app I get the error saying that libgds.dylib is missing. I have renamed the libfbclient.dylib to libgds.dylib. I have even made a copy in the original path and done a symbolic link to the /usr/local/lib folder (as is the case with libfbclient.dylib).
Here is what I have tried...

1. I have added '/usr/local/lib' to the paths in the target profile.
2. I have tried copying the file into the package
3. I have copied the file to my windows machine and then distribute it using the project deployment options.

Nothing appears to work. I'm not trying to create a redistributable package at this point. I just want to get the app working for debug.

One further bit of information. I installed the standard Firebird package rather than the Lipo package. I confess to not really understanding the difference. I am going to try installing the Lipo package now to see if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: @Peter: First, this is not a `Borland` tool, and hasn't been for several years. Second, your comment is not constructive. If you don't like using certain products, don't use them. Please don't post the noise here.

Comment: +1. Nicely asked question, and what you've tried is clearly explained.

Comment: One further bit of information. I installed the standard Firebird package rather than the Lipo package. I confess to not really understanding the difference. I am going to try installing the Lipo package now to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Martin, you should [edit] your question and add that last bit of information there, so people can see it; with it in the comments, they might not.

Comment: Yes, I did wonder if I should have done that.

Comment: First it was, then it wasn't, then it was again. And now, apparently it isn't again. Actually I quite liked Firebird. I ditched it because it never really took off as OSS and this is the reason documentation and community are a bit thin on the ground. I may have taken a flippant tone, but I think it reasonable to call into doubt the wisdom of choosing tools for which support is meagre and declining. To ignore this caution is of course your own prerogative. Incidentally, I still have printed manuals if you value them and want to pay postage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. The problem was the package that I installed.
After installing the Lipo package it appeared to find the dylib and continue.

Im not there yet as now I am getting a Permission Denied error trying to create the database  in the Documents folder. I guess I will post another question if I cant get to the bottom of this one.

Comment: @Wodzu he probably cannot do it until 2 days pass by

Comment: @Arioch'The I vaguely remembered there could be such constraint attached;)

Comment: Can you post the exact version that worked for you (Lipo? What is that even?)

Comment: The version that I used is FirebirdCS 2.5.2-26540-0-lipo-x86_64
I installed in on a Core Duo Mac Mini running Mountain Lion.

Comment: Okay that's good. a Full filename rather than a nickname will help the next person who comes along and has no idea what slang or partial names means.